# Print the first item in list, wrong output

Tags: python

code:

```
 # open some file
    for line in fp:
        list = line.strip().split();
        list = str(data_list);
        print(list[0]);
```

My output:

```
[
```

Expected Output: `2,500,000.00
                  some other number, only first item in every list`

In my list:

```
['2,500,000.00', '—', '2,999,999.99', '6,871', '158,164,946', '99.98619', '18,747,446,313.27', '2,728,488.77']
and more......
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(data_list[0])`?

Comment: You could start by printing out your whole array with "print(list)". Then you will see, whether it's a problem with the array itself or with the index.

Comment: Why are you converting your list to a string?  The first item in a string is the first character; the first item of the list is probably what you want.

Comment: @zondo sorry, wasn't think straight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it's not a list. You are converting list into a string:

```
    list = str(data_list);
    print(list[0]);
```

, remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Just make sure you accept the answer if it solves your problem.